# Html 5 video play with http headers?

Tags: html, http-headers, html5-video

How to play by adding a headers from a link with html 5?
For example:
xxxx.comv?v=36474, this link does not open without certain http headers, my question is when we want to play with html5, do we have a chance to add these http headers? 
I need to add hedaers:

`"authority: xxx.xxx.xy"
"user-agent: Mozilla" 
"sec-fetch-dest: empty"
"accept: */*" 
"origin: https://www.yyyy.com" 
"sec-fetch-site: cross-site" 
"sec-fetch-mode: cors"
"referer: https://www.yyyy.com/p4p.php?v=7f0baeb86d31f0bdb56d452d83020aaf52f0c7a1401c10ab10e4141629d9682b"
 "accept-language: tr-TR,tr;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7"`

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:html5-video]?!

Comment: Because the video needs a referer to play

Answer (score 0):

There are only **very** limited things you can do to affect the request headers sent when a link is clicked on (such as using [`rel="noreferrer"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Link_types).

You can't set arbitrary headers to arbitrary values.

If you are using `XMLHttpRequest` or `fetch` instead of a link then there are methods to set headers, but [a number of the headers you want to set are forbidden](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#forbidden-header-name), so that won't work either.

Comment: what about crossorigin=use-credentials